# Is it possible in any browser to find text on a webpage using search and "clicking" it without the mouse?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, browser

Lets say I have a page with 1000 blue links stacked on top of one another. I want to find one that matches pattern "blah" so I press ctrl-F/cmd-F and type in "blah". I find the link, it's highlighted for me. Here's my question...

Now that the browser has highlighted this link, is there anyway I can "click" on it instead of having to grab the mouse? I basically want to move my tab focus to it so I can just press enter and move on.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe with something like [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or a JS bookmarklet.. but this is something you should ask on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I discovered that this feature is already implemented in Chrome: just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. :)